# robot connection

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i've got a robot system for which a socket connection can be used to communicate. What is the best place to start with an example to construct the ros node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9539/robot-connection/) by [Reemco](https://answers.ros.org/users/340/reemco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best place to start is the ROS tutorials: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials.  You'll have to write a piece of code that reads/writes the socket, and publishes/subscribes to ROS topics.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1